# Magento update from 1.7 to 2.1

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to update magento but I'm having several problems with the db. First of all i did a magento fresh install, then I imported my db from command line, and I renamed the tables indicated in this (http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-database-structure/). 
Now, magento gives me this error:

```
 Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Store schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Store data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Directory schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Directory data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Theme schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Theme data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Backend schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Backend data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Backup schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Backup data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Eav schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Eav data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Customer schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.9
Magento_Customer data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.9
Magento_BundleImportExport schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_BundleImportExport data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_AdminNotification schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_AdminNotification data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CacheInvalidate schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CacheInvalidate data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Indexer schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Indexer data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Cms schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Cms data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_CatalogImportExport schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogImportExport data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Catalog schema: current version - none, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Catalog data: current version - none, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Rule schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Rule data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Msrp schema: current version - none, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Msrp data: current version - none, required version - 2.1.3
Magento_Search schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.4
Magento_Search data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.4
Magento_Bundle schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.2
Magento_Bundle data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.2
Magento_Quote schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_Quote data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

ecc...
```

Running bin/magento setup:upgrade i get the following errors:

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                       
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `prod_store_website` (`website_id`, `code`, `name`, `sort_order`, `default_group_id`,`is_default`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)       

[PDOException]                                                                      
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key  'PRIMARY'
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 is a rewritten system and is not backwards compatible with magento 1.x. It shares similar database structure and many tables have even the same names but migrating from 1.x to 2.x is not a task similar to upgrading 1.7 to 1.8. If you want to do that and move your data to the new system you need to use migration data tools:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html